# How to use Cocoa framework in Apple iOS applicaiton

Tags: ios, cocoa, frameworks, import

I am developing an iPhone application. In my iPhone application, I am using the `view-based` application template. Now I want to use the `Cocoa` framework for using `NSOpenPanelController` in my iOS application. How do I use the Cocoa framework, and where do I use it in iOS? Can somebody please explain this to me in detail?

When I start a new project in iOS, it will by default add the frameworks `UIKit` and `coreGraphics`. But when I started a new `Cocoa` application, the default frameworks available are `Foundation`, `Cocoa` and `Appkit`.

I dragged the `Cocoa` framework from the `Cocoa` application to my ios application. That step is successful, but when I started build and run, then it again asked for `AppKit` framework. I dragged that one too in the same manner as `Cocoa`. Then it asked for `foundation` framework. In both the applications for iOS and Cocoa applications, `foundation` framework is different. How to do this? Please help.

Comment: The cocoa framework is pretty big mate - a book would be a better place to start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cocoa is only available to Mac OS X (desktop) applications. UIKit is only available to iOS applications. You cannot mix and match the two, as there is no system that has both. (You may be able to get some applications to use both in the Simulator, but they will fail to build for the actual device.)

iOS does not expose the file system to the user, so there is no equivalent to NSOpenPanel available. You will need to choose a different approach to whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: It's worth noting that Cocoa pulls UIKit, Foundation and Core Data, and the latter two are actually available on the iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the AppKit (OS X) framework for iOS development any more than you can use UIKit (iOS) for developing OS X applications. They are designed for totally different uses, interaction models and hardware.

What you are attempting will not work.